# Flashed wrong ROM on tablet and stuck in blue screen with no recovery screen

Tags: custom-roms

Device specs:

- CPU: Allwinner A31S, Quad Core ARMv7 Processor (VFPv4, NEON)
- GPU: PowerVR SGX 544MP
- Motherboard: INGENIC-CROSS Q8S-v1.0 2013-04-22
- Version of Android: 4.2.2
- Build Number: fiber_q8s-eng 4.2.2 JDQ39 20130723 test-keys

Nothing is visible on the screen except for a blue screen. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Do a Google search for "A31S Q8S-1.0" and you get the following link to the Baidu file store where many Chinese ROMs are located.

(13) H8C-3G 全志A31S Q8S-V1.0.rar - 百度云网盘
http://pan.baidu.com/wap/link?uk=2471183759&shareid=3994280233&third=1

文件名:(13) H8C-3G 全志A31S Q8S-V1.0.rar 文件大小:323.08M 分享者:惠泽客服售后分享时间:2014-10-25 21:30 下载次数:4.

Cheers,

=ccflasher=